# DynamoDB for listing all items in the table using GSI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table like this in dynamodb

| name(PK) | key(SK) | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| read | user | Read User |
| read | account | Read Account |
| write | user | Write User |

I want to list all data from the table, but I don't want to perform a scan on the table. So I added an index on the table `allIndex`. It's value will always be same(`all` in example)

| name(PK) | key(SK) | description | allIndex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| read | user | Read User | all |
| read | account | Read Account | all |
| write | user | Write User | all |

Now I can query using `allIndex` to list all data from a table. It's benefit would be all data will reside in the same partition in dynamodb's GSI. I wanted to know if this is a good idea to do so? or will it lead to a hot partition on GSI?

Comment: The scan operation is appropriate for your use case.  Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Wouldn't scan have to fetch data from each partition but since the GSI that I have created has the same key so the data would reside in the same partition and query on GSI would be faster as all data is in the same partition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scan` is an appropriate option for your use case.

`query` is preferred over `scan` when you are filtering a subset of the data in your application. The `scan` operation can be expensive because it has to read every item in your database. This is a bad idea if you're just fetching a few items.  However, if your access pattern requires you to read the entire database, `scan` *is* the best option.

Comment: Wouldn't scan have to fetch data from each partition but since the GSI that I have created has the same key so the data would reside in the same partition and query on GSI would be faster as all data is in the same partition?

Comment: DDB will only return 1MB of data at a time, regardless of whether or not you use scan or query. I can't imagine you'd get any performance benefit for putting your entire DB in the same partition.  Scan might be slower than query if you're searching your entire DB for a subset of items since you'd have to search the entire database to find the items you need.  However, if you're returning ALL items from the DB, I suspect the performance would be equivalent.

Comment: @rxyz yes Scan() will have to read multiple partitions, but you can request that it do so in [parallel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.ParallelScan)  Besides which if your GSI is big enough, you'll end up with multiple internal partitions there also even if the "partition" key is all the same.